# How to password protect trac?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a way to password protect the directory where Trac is installed? I tried protecting it with .htaccess but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Read [*Authentication, Authorization and Access Control* in the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) and try to follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If your .htaccess isn't working, I'd suggest you check your httpd.conf and check is AllowOverride is set to ALL and not NONE (that will enable your .htaccess).

But you could also open a configuration file that take care of TRAC in /etc/httpd/conf.d and add this bit of code:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/dictory">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Private Directory"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/htpasswd"
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Then create the htpasswd:

```
htpasswd -c /path/to/htpasswd username
```

Don't forget to restart apache and make sure mod_auth is enabled in your configuration file.